# Comparing the active cell value to the value of the cell before it (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

First off, thank you for clicking into my question

I want the code to go through a list of values in a sheet called "Tests" and copy those values into a sheet called "List". The values in "Tests" are sometimes repeated though and I only want "List" to have unrepeated values.

Example:

"Tests" column A: dog, dog, cat, rabbit, rabbit, rabbit, turtle, turtle

"List" column A: dog, cat, rabbit, turtle

Can someone please point me in the right direction/ tell me where I went wrong? This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

'create new sheet
' ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

'adds a sheet and names it "List"
Sheets.Add.Name = "List"

'Select sheet1 (Tests)
Sheets("Tests").Activate

'Activate cell A2 in Tests -- not really necessary but ill leave it for now
Range("A2").Activate

'Create for loop for cells a2 through a1019
Dim cell As Integer
Dim listcell As Integer
listcell = 1



    For cell = 2 To 1019

    'create if statement for if Tests cell does match previous cell
    If (StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
            
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tests").Range("A" & (cell + 1)).Select
            Sheets("List").Range("A" & listcell).Value = Sheets("Tests").Range("A" & cell).Value
            listcell = listcell + 1

    'else if doesn't match then write down and move to next cell in sheet
    ElseIf (StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
            
            Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A" & cell)
            Sheets("List").Range("A" & listcell).Value = Sheets("Tests").Range("A" & cell).Value
            listcell = listcell + 1
    
    ElseIf (StrComp(ActiveCell.Value, ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, vbTextCompare) = -1) Then
        
            Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("A" & cell)
            Sheets("List").Range("A" & listcell).Value = Sheets("Tests").Range("A" & cell).Value
            listcell = listcell + 1

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No VBA necessary - you could use the `UNIQUE` worksheet function

Comment: ... or use Power Query to return a unique list.  ... or use conditional formatting to flag duplicates and use the format to determine which rows to delete.   ...or output the data to a table formatted pivot table.   There are a lot of easier methods than walking your entire dataset and doing row by row comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use VBA as part of a bigger process that uses VBA or just don't like using functions that spill, then you can still use unique

```
Dim lArray As Variant
lArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(Thisworkbook.worksheets("Tests").range("A1:A1290"))
```

Then once you have it in a vba array, it is nearly trivial to put it somewhere else in your workbook.  You might have to trap for the case where only 1 value is unique, since that looks like it puts it in a 1D array instead of a 2D array.

Comment: Also note that Empty cells are treated differently than cells with empty strings if you use unique.  Your string comparison method wouldn't make that distinction, so if that's an undesired feature, you'd have to trap for that.